# how to link one html file to multiple servlets

Tags: java, html, servlets

Hello I'm designing a simple login module  which contains username and password by using HTML, CSS in front-end and servlets in the back-end.  I'm using Netbeans as my IDE...

Initially user can login using `index.html` with his username and password.  Problem is after the user's login is successful (all the verification in the back-end database is successful in `logincheckservlet.java`) he/she is redirected to `login.html`. Now I want to use this (logged in) user's username for executing another query in `login.html`'s back-end servlet, but I cannot pass the username to the servlet I want because I'm already using requestDispatcher to redirect to login.html if login validation is successful...

I heard that I can solve my problem by using JSP but I don't want to.

Is there any other way I can solve the problem?

```
int i=ps.executeUpdate();
if(i == 1)
{
  out.println("You are Successfully Logged In");
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
  rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: you can use the session to store the user and make use of it any where in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Session you can do this easily. After getting user name in servlet set the value to session variable shown bellow.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("username", username);
```

then use it session variable in any place by bellow code

```
String user=session.getAttribute("username").toString();
```

Comment: i created session. When i'm using session variable in another servlet, it says: cannot find variable "session" even though i imported all the required packages.

Comment: Got It.  It Helped.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of servlet chanining.

```
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {


  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request , 
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException , IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    name = request.getParameter("name");

    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/secondservlet");

    if(name!=null) {
      request.setAttribute("UserName",name);
      rd.forward(request , response);
      // Forward the value to another Secondservlet
    }
}

}
```

Second Servlet:

```
public class secondservlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request , 
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException , IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String UserName = (String)request.getAttribute("UserName");

    out.println("The UserName is "+ UserName);

  }



}
```

Comment: Can i send the details of my form to multiple servlets ?

Comment: @SandeepA yes you can

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just write more than one form in same html page for different servlets in same html page.As for as saving the username and password you can make use of session and cookies which can be read by any servlet in same project.